# command line browser-sync detects changes, doesn't refresh page

Tags: node.js, browser-sync

I'm running browser-sync (2.7.1) on a Mac (10.10.3). I'm running it from the command line:

```
browser-sync start --proxy="192.168.3.49:8080" --files="public/css/main.css"
```

and I'm making changes to a css file, and BS detects the changes:

```
[BS] Watching files...
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
[BS] File changed: public/css/main.css
[BS] File changed: public/css/main.css
[BS] File changed: public/css/main.css
```

but my browsers aren't being updated.

This was working fine a couple days ago, I had updated npm modules, Xcode, but don't remember specifically something breaking it, so I reinstalled it.

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this. Can someone help?

Comment: If I sudo it, it work, so permissions error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had prefixfree.js included, so it rewrites the css and prevents BS from working.